# How to delete a JSON property by storing its reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object stored in a scope variable, say $scope.items.

```
 $scope.items =  
    [  
       {  
          "id":"1",
          "class":"group",
          "label":"ABC",
          "child":[  
             {  
                "id":"2",
                "label":"Reference number",
                "value":"11AA"
             },
             {  
                "id":"3",
                "label":"Received on",
                "value":"3rd Oct"
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "id":"4",
          "class":"group",
          "label":"XYZ",
          "child":[  
             {  
                "id":"5",
                "label":"Name",
                "value":"John"
             },
             {  
                "id":"6",
                "label":"Contact",
                "value":"54545882"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

I need to delete the JSON element based on the 'id' I receive from the backend. For now, lets say the property with id 6 has to be deleted.

```
delete $scope.items[1].child.splice(1,1); // THIS WORKS!
```

But, I need to do something like this:

```
var temp = $scope.items[1].child.splice(1,1);
delete temp;
```

However this does not work as 'temp' does not store the reference of the JSON element (with id 6) to be deleted.

Since I'm getting the path of the JSON element in the object to be deleted dynamically, I somehow need to store the reference and later perform the delete operation. Or please suggest me a best alternate to do so. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that [actually works how you think it does](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the path to be dynamic, store the important path elements in variables like this:

```
var itemNum = 1;
var childNum = 1;
```

Your code can dynamically set these variables using whatever logic is necessary. Then later in your code when you need to delete, do this:

```
$scope.items[itemNum].child.splice(items, 1);
```

You don't need the `delete` command here.  Just use `splice` to remove the item from the `child[]` array.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this, but how would this work if the 'child' has further child elements and is deeply nested? I will have to somehow loop through to achieve something like :                   $scope.items[1].child[1].child[2].child[0].splice(2, 1);

Answer (score 0):

First, that's an array of objects, not JSON.

Second, `Array.splice()` will remove a range of items from an array and return those items as a new array. When you splice the items out of the array, Angular should recognize the scope change and update the DOM, you don't have to `delete` anything.

Third, the `temp` variable will contain the returned list of removed elements, which you can index or iterate over.

```
var temp = $scope.items[1].child.splice(1,1);

console.log(temp[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete by storing in a variable like(var temp = $scope.items[1].child.splice(1,1);). Since 'var' create non-configurable properties that cannot be deleted with the delete operator.